# How to use this asymptotic formula for the sum of $\omega(n)$ for odd $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, notation, asymptotics

I'm looking for a good approximation of the following sum:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\omega\left(n\right)$$
where $n$ is **odd**.

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function) for the prime omega function, there is a section called: **Example I: A modified summatory function**. In that section there is that formula:

$$ S_{odd}\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{2}\log\log x+\frac{\left(2B_{1}-1\right)x}{4}+\left\{ \frac{x}{4}\right\} -\left[x\equiv2,3\mod4\right]_{\delta}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right) $$

If I read correctly, I think this is exactly what I need, but there are some parts I don't understand. When I use only the first 2 terms, I already get a good approximation, but I would like if someone could explain these:  $$\left\{ \frac{x}{4}\right\} $$
$$\left[x\equiv2,3\mod4\right]_{\delta}$$

Comment: $\{a\}=a-\lfloor a\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $a$

Comment: $[x\equiv2,3\bmod4]_\delta$ is $1$ if $x \equiv 2,3\bmod4$ and $0$ otherwise; cf. [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'll try that, or maybe not, after all both terms will give me a total of +-1, which is insignificant for what I need. Thanks anyway, at least I learned the notation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left\{ \dfrac{x}{4}\right\} =\dfrac{x}{4}\ -\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{x}{4}
\bigg\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $\dfrac x4$,

and $\left[x\equiv2,3\mod4\right]_{\delta}$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), which means it is $1$ if $x\equiv 2, 3\bmod 4$, and it is $0$ otherwise.